# How to validate Android's inapp purchase receipts via PHP/Java?

Tags: java, php, android, validation, receipt

One of our apps on Android is currently quite vulnerable to IAP hacking. We want to avoid this as this will ruin some network-based systems and also harm our revenue.

We would like to know is there a way to validate the purchase receipt before we give him item. Thank you very much.

Also sorry for my extremely bad english, they may sound rude at some point(someone told me) but I am actually being very polite.:)

Comment: The scope of this question is far too large. This is possible if you run your own external web service to register purchases with alongside the IAP process.

Comment: With bad english+bad programming knowledge(I am a game designer but not programmer) I couldn't perfectly understand. Do you mean creating another service/database by ourselves to register and track the process? Thank you, Scott!

Comment: Yes, you would need to run your own web server and web service to have validation outside of the standard IAP process.

Comment: Okay, I think the scope is really too large that our team couldn't handle this...

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to use [Purchase Status API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html)

You will do the billing process on the client side, and once done, you will send the token to the server, and then, be able to check the status of a purchase.

If the status is what you expect, then you will enable or send the update to the user.

Comment: Not sure how this can help. We can check that the purchase is purchased and not consumed. But we cannot make sure, that the client app updates the purchase status to consumed.